# How to improve execution time of a Laravel Query Builder generated SQL query

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-optimization

I have three tables that are concerned by this query

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `latName` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `araName` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `img_name` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rgba_color` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `overlay` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mdi_icon` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tags_latname_unique` (`latName`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tags_araname_unique` (`araName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

```
 CREATE TABLE `newspapers` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `latName` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `araName` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `img_name` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `newspapers_latname_unique` (`latName`),
  UNIQUE KEY `newspapers_araname_unique` (`araName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `newspaper_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `seen` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `img_name` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `paragraph` text NOT NULL,
  `read_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `articles_link_unique` (`link`),
  UNIQUE KEY `articles_img_name_unique` (`img_name`),
  KEY `articles_newspaper_id_foreign` (`newspaper_id`),
  KEY `articles_tag_id_foreign` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `articles_newspaper_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`newspaper_id`) REFERENCES `newspapers` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `articles_tag_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47421 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

Basically, I want to load the latest 5 articles (ordered by date) that have an active newspaper and active tag.

Right now articles table contains about 40k entries.

This is the query generated by Laravel's query builder

```
SELECT `articles`.*
FROM `articles`
INNER JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `articles`.`tag_id`
  AND `tags`.`active` = 1
INNER JOIN `newspapers` ON `newspapers`.`id` = `articles`.`newspaper_id`
  AND `newspapers`.`active` = 1
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

It takes Mysql about 6sec to run the query, when I remove the `ORDER BY` clause, the query becomes very fast (0.001sec).

Here is the query explanation:

```
+------+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys                                         | key                           | key_len | ref                    | rows | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | newspapers | ALL    | PRIMARY                                               | NULL                          | NULL    | NULL                   | 18   | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | articles   | ref    | articles_newspaper_id_foreign,articles_tag_id_foreign | articles_newspaper_id_foreign | 8       | mouhim.newspapers.id   | 1127 |                                              |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | tags       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                               | PRIMARY                       | 8       | mouhim.articles.tag_id | 1    | Using where                                  |
+------+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I tried creating an index on the date attribute but it didn't help.

for convenience, this is how I am using Query Builder for this query:

```php
Article::select("articles.*")
    ->join("tags", function ($join) {
        $join->on("tags.id", "articles.tag_id")
            ->where("tags.active", 1);
    })
    ->join("newspapers", function ($join) {
        $join->on("newspapers.id", "articles.newspaper_id")
            ->where("newspapers.active", 1);
    })
        ->orderBy("date", "desc")
        ->paginate(5)
```

At first, I was using Eloquent (whereHas) but Eloquent was generating non optimized query using (where exists), so I had to go the joins way.

What can I do to improve execution time of this query?

Result of `SHOW INDEXES FROM articles;`

```
+----------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name                      | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| articles |          0 | PRIMARY                       |            1 | id           | A         |       36072 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| articles |          0 | articles_link_unique          |            1 | link         | A         |       36072 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| articles |          0 | articles_img_name_unique      |            1 | img_name     | A         |       36072 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| articles |          1 | articles_newspaper_id_foreign |            1 | newspaper_id | A         |          32 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| articles |          1 | articles_tag_id_foreign       |            1 | tag_id       | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| articles |          1 | data                          |            1 | date         | A         |       36072 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
```

---

This query was suggested by [Rick James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766831/rick-james) as a solution

```
SELECT  `articles`.*
FROM  `articles`     
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tags WHERE id = `articles`.`tag_id` and active = 1)
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM newspapers WHERE id = `articles`.`newspaper_id` and active = 1)     
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT  5;
```

Running EXPLAIN on this query yields the following result

```
+------+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys                                         | key                           | key_len | ref                    | rows | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | newspapers | ALL    | PRIMARY                                               | NULL                          | NULL    | NULL                   | 18   | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | articles   | ref    | articles_newspaper_id_foreign,articles_tag_id_foreign | articles_newspaper_id_foreign | 8       | mouhim.newspapers.id   | 1127 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | tags       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                               | PRIMARY                       | 8       | mouhim.articles.tag_id | 1    | Using where                                  |
+------+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: no matter how much you optimize your query, the table will be increasing day by day  and so the loading time will follow. Did you try yajra-datatable (server-side) ?

Comment: yes indeed the size will get bigger, but I think MySQL should be able to handle this amount of data very quickly ?

Comment: Do an explain on the query (`EXPLAIN SELECT...`) and [edit] the results into your question. This may provide some more helpful information.

Comment: @miken32 I have added the result of ```EXPLAIN```. Thank you!

Comment: This is with the `ORDER BY` clause and the index in place?

Comment: yes it is. I am creating the index like this ```CREATE INDEX date ON articles(date)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want dups, change to this; it is likely to be much faster:

```
SELECT  `articles`.*
    FROM  `articles`
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tags
                        WHERE id = `articles`.`tag_id` )
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM newspapers
                        WHERE id = `articles`.`newspaper_id` )
    ORDER BY  `date` DESC
    LIMIT  5;
```

Also, have this index on `articles`:

```
INDEX(date)
```

(This is a *rare* use case for *starting* index with a column that will be used in a 'range'.)

(Sorry, I don't speak 'Laravel'; maybe someone else can help with that part.)

PS.  Having 3 UNIQUE keys on a table is highly unusual.  It often indicates a problem with the schema design.

> each article has one and only one Tag associated with it

Can multiple articles have the same Tag?

> when I remove the ORDER BY clause, the query becomes very fast (0.001sec).

That is because you get whatever 5 rows are easy to return to you.  Clearly the `ORDER BY` is part of the requirement.  "Using temporary; Using filesort" says there was at least a sort.  It will actually be a "file" sort -- because `SELECT *` includes a `TEXT` column.  (There is a technique to avoid "file", but I don't think it is needed here.)

Comment: No worries regarding Laravel, at this point I just want to understand and improve the query (I could translate it to Laravel afterwards). I am already putting an index on `date` : ```CREATE INDEX date ON articles(date);```

... the relation between the 3 tables is as follows: each Article has one and only one Tag, and one and only one Newspaper.

I want to retrieve articles that have both active tags and newspapers (and get only the last 5 ones)

Comment: and yes, multiple articles can have the same tag and same newspaper..... there are 9 tags and 30 newspapers, and there are 40k article.

Comment: @HamzaMogni - I added some more.

Comment: How many of the 40K articles are "active"?  (If most are inactive, my suggested query may have performance issues.)

Comment: no most of them would fill the condition of having both an active tag and newspaper.

Comment: I tried the query you suggested and it is still taking the same amount of time (roughly 3.9sec)... with the index on date placed.

Comment: I have added the list of indexes I have on the articles table.

Comment: would creating another table ActiveArticles(article_id, article_date, tag_id, newspaper_id) help with avoiding the file sort ? (the table would include only article ids for articles fulfilling the criteria: active tag and newspaper) ?

Comment: Hmmm... Can you provide the EXPLAIN for my formulation.  What version of MySQL?

Comment: Rather than creating another table, add `active` to `articles` and have `INDEX(active, date)`.  The you can get rid of the `JOINs`.  But you would need to turn on/off `articles.active` whenever the corresponding `tag` or `newspaper` is turned on/off.

Comment: Thank you for the suggested solution; I have also added the EXPLAIN result for your formulation.

Comment: @HamzaMogni - Oh well, the Optimizer is smart enough to turn my formulation into yours!  I dislike using "index hints", but `FORCE INDEX('data')` may be the solution.

Comment: forcing the index indeed does make the query fast (0.001sec). So in order to fix this properly I should either rethink my schema or add ```active``` to ```articles``` right? . Thank you for your help and your time!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the two queries are supposed to be same, but they are not.

Anyway for the second query I think this should be better

```
Article::leftJoin('tags', 'articles.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id)
   ->where('tags.latName', $tag)
   ->orderBy("articles.date", "desc")
   ->select(['articles.*'])
   ->paginate(5);
```

The problem is probably, that the subquery you created in whereIn is slowing it down and whereIn itself may as well slow your query. This may be eased by using join and where.

As for the first query, can you show how you did the index for date? :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I have corrected the Eloquent Query I am using and updated my question (by mistake I copied the wrong function to my question, I am deeply sorry... check my edited answer for the query I am actually using).... As for the index, I have created it by ```CRETE INDEX date_index ON articles(date);```

Comment: Can there be multiple "active tags" for a single article?  If so, I contend that your query will give you dups that you don't want.

Comment: Hey @RickJames, No there will never be duplicates as the relationship between the two is One to Many; hence each article has one and only one Tag associated with it.